# Null Pointer Exception in Java Enum

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I'm learning Enum concept in java and I faced a problem while practicing.

Here is the code snippet,

```java
public class MyClass {
    private String cardColor = CARDS.SPADE.cardColor; #Causes Null Pointer #Default Value
    private MyClass(CARDS card){
        this.cardColor = card.cardColor;
    }
    public static enum CARDS{
        SPADE("Black"),
        CLUB("Black"),
        DIAMOND("Red"),
        HEART("Red");
        private String cardColor = null;
        private MyClass obj = null;
        CARDS(String color){
            this.cardColor = color;
            obj = new MyClass(this);         #Trying to create object for MyClass 
        }
        public String getCardColor(){
            return this.cardColor;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(CARDS.SPADE);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a MyClass object private to the enum in it's constructor. Here the value CARDS.SPADE is null and I end up with Null Pointer Exception.

If I don't create an object in enum constructor everything works perfect,

> obj = new MyClass(this);

I'm not understanding why the static enum is not initialized and I'm confused with the control flow here. Can someone explain me what's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to create an instance of the parent class *inside* the `enum`? From what you have posted, it looks more like you want to have an instance of `Cards` as a class attribute of `MyClass`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The MyClass has a private constructor and here I'm trying to have only single MyClass instance for each of the enum cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency : the initialization of the `CARDS` enum and the `MyClass` instance depend on each other.
`CARDS` constructor instantiates `MyClass` but `MyClass` constructor relies itself on the `CARDS.SPADE` state that is not still fully initialized as in the pending enum constructor.

Either break this cycle or do things in two times. Init the enum without the bidirectional relationship and after the constructor invocations, set the enum value to the `MyClass` instance via a setter.

Note that the "real" cause of the `NullPointerException` is that you don't refer to the currently instance created in the enum constructor (`this`) but you refer the enum value from the enum class itself : `MyClass.CARD.SPADE`.
The first has a state but the second not yet since the enum constructor has not returned yet.

By passing the enum instance into the constructor of `MyClass` it will "work" :

```
CARDS(String color){
        this.cardColor = color;
        obj = new MyClass(this);    
    }
}

// ...
public MyClass(CARDS cards){
     cardColor = cards.cardColor;
}
```

But in a general way, passing `this` during constructor body to another object/class not a good idea.   This *may* leak to an inconsistent state if the object states changes between this time and the end of the constructor invocation.

Comment: Is there is any way to initialize the cardColor of MyClass to default value like color of spade ?