# What is the explanation of null values in a cyclic dependency in final private enum fields?

Tags: java, enums, nullpointerexception, jls, cyclic-reference

Consider these enum declarations:

```
enum Color {
    RED(Shape.CIRCLE),
    GREEN(Shape.TRIANGLE),
    BLUE(Shape.SQUARE);

    private final Shape shape;

    Color(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }
}

enum Shape {
    CIRCLE(Color.RED),
    TRIANGLE(Color.GREEN),
    SQUARE(Color.BLUE);

    private final Color color;

    Shape(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

There are cyclic dependencies between the enum fields. There are no compiler warnings (using Java 8).

However, all these tests will fail in the second line:

```
@Test
public void testRedAndCircle() {
    assertThat(Color.RED.getShape()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(Shape.CIRCLE.getColor()).isNotNull(); // fails
}

@Test
public void testCircleAndRed() {
    assertThat(Shape.CIRCLE.getColor()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(Color.RED.getShape()).isNotNull(); // fails
}

@Test
public void testGreenAndTriangle() {
    assertThat(Color.GREEN.getShape()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(Shape.TRIANGLE.getColor()).isNotNull(); // fails
}

@Test
public void testBlueAndSquare() {
    assertThat(Color.BLUE.getShape()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(Shape.SQUARE.getColor()).isNotNull(); // fails
}
```

How can the null value in the enum field be explained?

It seems that the enum object in the private final fields is not yet completely instantiated.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661077/null-pointer-exception-in-java-enum

Comment: What's the error given when they fail?

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz the second `assertThat( ... ).isNotNull()` fails with "Expecting actual not to be null", which means that the `get...()` returns null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to break the cycle is to make the evaluation lazy in at least one of the enums, thus allowing the other to get initialised before being used. E.g.:

```
enum Color {
    RED(() -> Shape.CIRCLE),
    GREEN(() -> Shape.TRIANGLE),
    BLUE(() -> Shape.SQUARE);

    private final Supplier<Shape> shape;

    Color(Supplier<Shape> shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    Shape getShape() {
        return shape.get();
    }
}

enum Shape {
    CIRCLE(Color.RED),
    TRIANGLE(Color.GREEN),
    SQUARE(Color.BLUE);

    private final Color color;

    Shape(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

But I would strongly advice that you revisit your design, as cyclic dependencies are usually a code smell. If shapes are not of a certain color by their nature and the other way around, you probably need a separate abstraction that defines "red circles" and "blue squares", which has nothing to do with merely being a "circle/square" or being "red/blue".

```
enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE }
enum Shape { CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, SQUARE }

enum ColoredShape {

    RED_CIRCLE(Shape.CIRCLE, Color.RED),
    GREEN_TRIANGLE(Shape.TRIANGLE, Color.GREEN),
    MAGENTA_TRIANGLE(...) // because why not? :)
    // ......

    private final Shape shape;
    private final Color color;


    ColoredShape(Shape shape, Color color) {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.color = color;
    }

    Color color() { return color; }
    Shape shape() { return shape; }

}
```

This makes it all explicit and renders colors and shapes reusable in contexts other than this very specific one.

---

Another major defect of your aproach is that it does not enforce that the pair choices match both ways. I.e. nothing stops me from defining e.g. `Color.RED(Shape.CIRCLE)` and `Shape.CIRCLE(Color.BLUE)`. So if you want this mapping to be consistent, you should define it in a single place and infer/reuse it the second time (or add some validation logic to ensure consistency).

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the problem is that when `Color` was being initialized, `Shape` was not initialized yet, hence the shape of the color ends up being `null`. Circular dependencies are signs of bad design, so I would fix the error in the plan. Instead, you could use the same numeric values for the pairs, like this:

```
enum Color {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE;

    Shape getShape() {
        return Shape.values()[ordinal()];
    }
}

enum Shape {
    CIRCLE,
    TRIANGLE,
    SQUARE;

    Color getColor() {
        return Color.values()[ordinal()];
    }
}
```

This way you have a reliable mapping and you can get the shape of the color or the color of the shape.

Comment: You don't need that value property (which you omitted, btw); and `valueOf` takes a string, not an index. Enums have a built-in `ordinal()` method for this, so I think what you meant was: `return Shape.values()[ordinal()]` and `return Color.values()[ordinal()]` respectively.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu thanks for pointing these out. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: No worries. Since we're friends now, I took the liberty to edit it further. Hope you won't mind.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu not at all. Multumesc for the edit!

Comment: That's a nicer way than my second suggestion, sadly I did not spot that the arrays are already declared.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Enum constants are initialized like static fields, so you get a similar outcome as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416481/1374678). Basically, to initialize one enum correctly, the other already needs to be fully initialized, and vice versa. Obviously, this is a circular dependency and cannot work.

As a result, the constants of the `Shape` enum are initialized before the initialization of `Color` is complete. Therefore, the fields corresponding to the `Color` constants `RED`, `GREEN`, and `BLUE` are still `null` when `Shape` accesses them during initialization.

By the way, it seems like any of the two enums could be the one that ends up incorrectly initialized, because the two form a symmetric cycle. However, [the order of initialization is determined by the order in which a class is first used](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) in the program code. In your tests, the `Color` enum is used first, and so its initialization is started first. Hence, the JVM loads the code of `Color`, which references `Shape`. Before the initalization of `Color` continues, the code of `Shape` is loaded. `Shape` in turn references `Color`, but since `Color` is already in the process of being intialized, `Shape`'s initialization continues, using the uninitialized fields of `Color`. Finally, `Color`'s initialization completes, and by now the fields of `Shape` contain the `Shape` constants, so `Color` initializes correctly.

### Solution

I would replace one of the getters, e.g., the one in `Shape` with something like this:

```
Color getColor() {
    for (Color c : Color.values()) {
        if (c.getShape() == this) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

This way, you don't need the `color` field in `Shape` and the circular dependency is avoided.

An added benefit is that the two enums are guaranteed to be consistent. A change in the `Color` enum will automatically be reflected in `Shape`.

And if you worry about performance ([I wouldn't](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/366400)), you could also keep the `color` field in `Shape` and initialize it the first time `getColor` is called:

```
Color getColor() {
    if (color == null) {
        for (Color c : Color.values()) {
            if (c.getShape() == this) {
                color = c;
                return color;
            }
        }
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
    return color;
}
```

Regarding thread-safety, it's not necessary to have any sort of synchronization here or to make the `color` field `volatile`. In case some thread does not see the initialization performed by another thread, it will simply redo the bit of work, but the result will be the same.